# Vue router, global guard "beforeEach" loop

Tags: vue.js, loops, vue-router, stack-overflow

I need a global navigation guard in Vue Router to perform some page changes without history recording.

When I navigate to certain pages (checked by a function `checkPagesToExclude`), I don't save history (passing the `replace` property in the `next()` function), so when I perform back navigation, I can go back to the first page before this certain pages navigation.

This is my code:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  let options = { name: to.name };

  if(checkPagesToExclude(to)){
    options.replace = true;
  }

  next(options);

})
```

The problem is that the browser gets to a stack overflow (`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`) at every navigation.
The navigation guard creates an infinite loop.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint and check which navigations cause it, and why. `let options = { name: to.name }` - this is a bad idea because you ignore other navigation options - params, etc. It's not guaranteed that each route has a name, unless you took care of it.

Comment: @EstusFlask i can confirm that all my route have a name configured.

Comment: In console i have only a warning from vue router:
[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation

And then the error:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at stringifyQuery (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:105)
    at getFullPath (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:210)
    at createRoute (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:164)
    at _createRoute (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1722)
    at Object.match (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1612)
    at VueRouter.match (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2930)
    at HashHistory.transitionTo (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2251)

Comment: Use a debugger. Currently only you can debug your case. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve